# Conditional prepareForSegue with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need have a conditional Segue. The possible option are:

- link have a children link -> I should reload the uicollectionview.
- link have not children link -> Go to the other windows.

This is my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loaddata(self.url) }

func loaddata(url: String){
    var loaded: Bool = false
    api.remoteUrl = url + self.end_url
    println(api.remoteUrl)

    api.getData({data, error -> Void in
        println("entro aqui")
        if (data != nil){
            println(data)
            // Fix possible error if no "results" key
            if let results = data["results"].array {
                self.delete_subcategory_withoutvideos(results)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                //self.colle  ctionView(<#collectionView: UICollectionView#>cellForItemAtIndexPath: <#NSIndexPath#>)

            }
            println("Data reloaded")
        } else {
            println("api.getData failed")
            println(error)
        }
        //println(self.result_category)
        loaded = true
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    })

    while (!loaded){}


}

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
    let index = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell) // this return -> NSIndexPath?
    if (self.result_category[index!.row]["children"].string != nil){
        self.loaddata(self.result_category[index!.row]["children"].string!)
    }else{
    let vc : VideosViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! VideosViewController
        vc.id_category =  self.result_category[index!.row]["id"].intValue
        println(vc.id_category)}

}
```

whit this code, when the link have a children link call to loaddata function but still go to other windows.

Thanks you so much friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. but may you don't know that prepare for segue always call when you are try to call or implement perform segue or push to other window. Your problem has a solution that make a cutom method to check your condition. Put below code in custom method.

```
func my_Function
{
 let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
let index = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell) // this return -> NSIndexPath?
if (self.result_category[index!.row]["children"].string != nil){
    self.loaddata(self.result_category[index!.row]["children"].string!)
}else{
let vc : VideosViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! VideosViewController
    vc.id_category =  self.result_category[index!.row]["id"].intValue
    println(vc.id_category)
}
```

Comment: ¿From where i should to call my custom function?¿i neeed to send to my custom function the "sender" param ?

Comment: no need of "sender" param and you can check this condition before calling prepare for segue. and best is that call this custom method where you will get indexpath easily and params also get easily when you can use did select delegate method for the collection view.